# Linking a contact submit form to an email in joomla 3

Tags: contacts, joomla3.0

I'm having a really difficult time with figuring out how to link a contact form to a specific email in joomla 3.

I've gone to Content --> Categories --> Contact --> and then clicked the Edit button. I've put the specific email into what I believe is the correct box and it doesn't work.

I've checked out a few tutorials on lynda.com, but nothing seems to work. Does anyone have any suggestions or a link they can send me to try and figure this out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to:

```
Components -> Contacts -> *Contact_Name
```

And set **Linked user** with the user account you want to receive **contact e-mails**.

Hope this helps